# Adding a device with data to a RAID0 config

Tags: linux, raid, amazon-web-services

If I have a device mounted in RHEL, how do I add another device to it and make it a RAID0 config?

I know how to mount two new devices in a RAID0 config, but how do I do it with one device that is already in use and has data on it?

EDIT:

My linux instance is on AWS EC-2. I have one EBS volume attached to it with data on it. And I attached another EBS volume to the instance. But, now I want to know how do I combine the two into a RAID0 while preserving the data.

I know how to create a RAID0 of two new devices. But, how do I do it if one device has a parition and data on it and the other is a new partition?

Comment: What does this have to do with amazon-s3?

Comment: nothing to do with S3...just EC2 and EBS

Comment: Thanks. I removed the amazon-s3 tag which you accidentally added to the question.

Answer (score 0):

RIAD 0 has no redundancy. To add it either:

1. Go to your real hardware cards firmware and add the new drive to the array. Lets it expand. (Assuming you have a real HW card and that it is capable of that. Some may, some will not).
2. Or make a good backup.
   Test the backup.
   Boot from something else that the array
   Kill the array
   . Create a new - bigger- array with the extra disk and restore the backup.

Given that RAID 0 is never used for anything important except speed, the last is probably the way to go.

Comment: forgot to add...I'm using EBS volumes on AWS. So I have one attached EBS volume with data...I attached a 2nd on and now I want to combine the two EBS volumes into Raid0

Comment: You might want to add that information to the original post using the [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/994969/edit) function.